# R ggplot2 legend with linetypes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am relatively new to R and I have some difficulties with ggplot2. I have a data frame consisting of three variables (`alpha`, `beta`, `gamma`) and I want to plot them together. I get the plot but I have two problems:

1. legend is outside the plot and I want it to be inside
2. linetypes are changed to "solid", "dashed" and "dotted"!

Any ideas/suggestions would be more than welcome!

```
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=my.data,aes(x = time, y = alpha,linetype = 'dashed')) +
  geom_line(data=my.data,aes(x = time, y = beta, linetype = 'dotdash')) +
  geom_line(data=my.data,aes(x = time, y = gamma,linetype = 'twodash')) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = "", labels = c("alpha", "beta", "gamma"))+
  theme_bw()+
  xlab('time (years)')+
  ylab('Mean optimal paths')
print(p)
```

Comment: Can you paste the result of `dput(my.data)`?

Comment: All of them are continuous variables. ```structure(list(time = c(...), alpha=c(...), beta=c(...), gamma=c(...),Names = c("time", 
"alpha", "beta", "gamma"), row.names = c(NA, -1000L), class = "data.frame")```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after is easier to achieve if you first rearrange your data to long format, with one observation per row.

You can do this with tidyr's `gather` function. Then you can simply map the linetype to the `variable` in your data.

In your original approach, you tried to assign a literal 'linetype' by using `aes()`, but ggplot interprets this as you saying, 'assign a line type here as if the variable that is mapped to linetype had the value dashed/dotdash/twodash'. When drawing the plot, it looks up the linetypes in the default scale_linetype_discrete, the first three values of which happen to be solid, dotted and dashed, which is why you're seeing the confusing replacement. You can specify linetypes by using `scale_linetype_manual`.

The position of the legend is adjustable in `theme()`.
`legend.position = c(0,1)` defines the legend to be placed at the left, top corner.
`legend.justification = c(0,1)` sets the anchor to use in `legend.position` to the left, top corner of the legend box.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Create some example data
my.data <- data.frame(
    time=1:100,
    alpha = rnorm(100),
    beta = rnorm(100),
    gamma = rnorm(100)
)

my.data <- my.data %>%
    gather(key="variable", value="value", alpha, beta, gamma)

p <- ggplot(data=my.data, aes(x=time, y=value, linetype=variable)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    values=c("solid", "dotdash", "twodash"), 
    name = "", 
    labels = c("alpha", "beta", "gamma")) +
  xlab('time (years)')+
  ylab('Mean optimal paths') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position=c(0.1, 0.9), legend.justification=c(0,1))
print(p)
```